# ORACLE SQL select max(count()) to year

Tags: sql, oracle, select, max

I have database of library and i am trying to assign most borrowed title to each year like

```
2015 - The Great Gatsby
2014 - Da vinci code
2013 - Harry Potter
....
```

I've tried this but i am not sure about it

```
select to_char(borrow_date,'YYYY'),title_name
from k_title
join k_book
using(title_id)
join k_rent_books
using(book_id)
group by to_char(borrow_date,'YYYY'),title_name
having count(title_id) = (
select max(cnt) FROM(select count(title_name) as cnt
from k_title
join k_book
using(title_id)
join k_rent_books
using(book_id)
group by title_id,title_name,to_char(borrow_date,'YYYY')));
```

I've got only 3 results

```
2016 - Shogun
2006 - The Revolt of Mamie Stover
1996 - The Great Gatsby
```

I will be happy for any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle has the nice capability to get the first or last value in an aggregation (as opposed to the `min()` or `max()`).  This requires using something called `keep`.

So, the way to express what you want to do is:

```
select yyyy,
       max(title_name) keep (dense_rank first order by cnt desc) as title_name
from (select to_char(borrow_date, 'YYYY') as yyyy,
             title_name, count(*) as cnt
      from k_title t join
           k_book b
           using (title_id) join
           k_rent_books
           using (book_id)
      group by to_char(borrow_date, 'YYYY'), title_name
    ) yt
group by yyyy;
```

Your query is returning the year/title combinations that have the overall maximum count over all years, not the maximum per year.